# how to save data before submitting to 3rd party server?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have been reading through lots of Q&A everywhere and these stackoverflow posts seem to be most related to what I am trying to do:
1) [How we can save data on two servers using one sumit form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868711/how-we-can-save-data-on-two-servers-using-one-sumit-form)
2) [How to call server side action method just before submitting form to 3rd party url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715069/how-to-call-server-side-action-method-just-before-submitting-form-to-3rd-party-u)

Basically, I am working with Aweber autoresponder service and I have been having some technical trouble where the leads don't seem to record in Aweber even though I see on my analytics software people are filling in the forms with emails and hitting the submit button.

So, I was hoping I can and capture the form data on my server first in a TXT file, before the form data gets submitted to Aweber.

(from my research I need ajax, jquery to achieve this)

Following different posts and tutorials, I have come up with the following but unfortunately is still not working...

Please let me know how to fix this code if possible.  THANK YOU so MUCH!!!

Head with jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    //if submit button is clicked
    $('#submit').submit(function () {       

        //Get the data from all the fields
        var email = $('input[name=email]');
        var custom_sub1 = $('input[name=custom sub1]');
        var custom_sub2 = $('input[name=custom sub2]');
        var custom_sub3 = $('input[name=custom sub3]');

        //organize the data properly
        var data = 'email=' + email.val() + '&custom_sub1=' + custom_sub1.val() + '&custom_sub2='
        + custom_sub2.val() + '&custom_sub3='  + custom_sub3.val();

        //start the ajax
        $.ajax({
            //this is the php file that processes the data and send mail
            url: "http://mydomain.com/form_plus_email.php",

            //method
            type: 'POST',

            //pass the data        
            data: data,    

            //Do not cache the page
            cache: false,

        success: function() {
            }
        });



        //cancel the submit button default behaviours
        return false;
    });
}); 


</script>
</head>
```

The above, I don't know if "return false;" is causing the problems

Body with form:

```
<form method="post" action="http://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl">

<input type="text" name="email" value="Enter email" id="email">

<input value="xxxxxxxxxxxx" name="meta_web_form_id" type="hidden">
<input value="" name="meta_split_id" type="hidden">
<input value="xxxxxxxxxxxxx" name="listname" type="hidden">
<input value="http://domain.com/thankyoupage" name="redirect" type="hidden">
<input value="http://domain.com/thankyoupage" name="meta_redirect_onlist" type="hidden">
<input value="xxxxxxxxxxxxx" name="meta_adtracking" type="hidden">
<input value="1" name="meta_message" type="hidden">
<input value="email" name="meta_required" type="hidden">
<input value="1" name="meta_forward_vars" type="hidden">
<input value="" name="meta_tooltip" type="hidden">
<script type="text/javascript">
{
document.write('<input type="hidden" name="custom sub1" value="'+sub1+'">')
document.write('<input type="hidden" name="custom sub2" value="'+sub2+'">')
document.write('<input type="hidden" name="custom sub3" value="'+sub3+'">')
}
</script>

<input type="image" value="Submit Button" name="submit" src="image.png" id="submit" class="button1">
        </form>



</body>
```

For Aweber, it is important all the fields listed both hidden and not hidden to be passed on to the action="http://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl".

However, for myself, as I am only interested in 4 fields, I have specify all that I need in the jquery section in the head tag.

I don't know why the code isn't working...  So, **how do I make sure it will save to my server first with ajax before** the form data is submitted to 3rd party url?  Right now...

```
<form method="post" action="http://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl">
```

is executing and working properly...  but the ajax does not save the data at all from what i can tell

Thank you so much!

Comment: Can't you just post it twice? You have a ` $.ajax` call that does one post, why not add a second ` $.ajax` below that one that does another, in the same click event? Just make sure you have your success function not redirect until both have finished.

Comment: @Nanne: thanks for the tip

I did try doing 2 ajax calls with the form action set to "#".  however, even with that, no ajax call was executing...

Just like with the current code, the action="http://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl" would execute but for some reason the ajax post doesn't seem to function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change the event on the submit button you use. So instead of

```
$('#submit').submit(function () {
```

use

```
$('#submit').click(function () {
```

as the submit event is for the form, not the button. Once you've changed that, then as Ramengo mentioned, use your success function to submit the form.

Better would be though be to use the Aweber API which allows you to add users to an account since November 2011.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just running out the door at the minute, but I just want to add that sometimes when you're having strange Ajax issues, try using GET instead of POST for the ajax call.. this has fixed many issues for me before and, since you're using ajax and the url isn't seen by the user, the differences are pretty subtle and irrelevant.

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: thanks for helping!

the thing is...  I don't know why the ajax call isn't being executed.
- is it because i have coded it wrong?
- is it because i am using improper syntax?
- is it because i am using the wrong functions?

what's the best way to troubleshoot ajax...

Answer (score -1):

Are you doing anything with:

```
    success: function() {
        }
    });
```

This will trigger on successful loading of the Ajax content and so, all you should need is:

```
    success: function() {
           $('#formid').submit();
        }
    });
```

Just make sure you have given your form an id you can easily use to refer to. If you don't set a behaviour for "success", then your form will never submit as you are stopping the submit behaviour with

```
return false;
```

Secondly, have you considered submitting the form to an intermediary script on your server that writes to file and then redirects to the destination 3rd party script?

That will save you having to figure out how to use Ajax if you are not familiar with it.

Comment: He is later getting the value out, via `email.val()`.

Comment: thank you for your response Ramengo. I will try out your suggestions!

the reason why I can't submit the form to an intermediary script on my server is because then all the leads will be coming from my server ip...  which will be frowned upon by Aweber

Comment: @HarryPotter: Ignore this, as you're getting the value of your email field, etc, on the next line of code: `var data = 'email=' + email.val() + '&custom_sub1=' + custom_sub1.val() + '&custom_sub2='
        + custom_sub2.val() + '&custom_sub3='  + custom_sub3.val();
`

Comment: @HarryPotter if you use an intermediary script that redirects, surely the referring URL will be same as if you were doing so from the original form. As long as you are not submitting server side using Curl or similar but redirecting with full URL parameters, this should emulate the form submission.

Comment: @Ramengo, thanks for the reply!  I don't know how to this intermediary script would look then...  Is there an example script I can reference to and try to figure it out?

Comment: @HarryPotter it's a bit late here but I can try to give it a bash after tomorrow. In general terms this is how it would work: Form submits to php script, script processes and writes to file, script uses headers and builds the destination url as it would have been if submitted by the form and redirects using a 301. Look at : http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php . There may be more elegant ways but, off the top of my head and as a way to troubleshoot your current issues, this would be my approach.

Comment: @Ramengo, thanks for the fast response again.  If possible, that would be awesome if you could send over something tomorrow.  In the meantime, I will try and figure it out (although I am just as fresh in php as I am in ajax...)